# Does exist an 'in' operator for Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I mean something like this:

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.type in('A', 'B', 'C')">lorem ipsum</div>
```

To use in the place of several ORs:

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.type == 'A' || ctrl.type == 'B' || ctrl.type == 'C'">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No angular-related, but you can use native JS method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

`['A', 'B', 'C'].includes(ctrl.type)`

though this one is ES6 addition and only supported in very recent browsers, so you should polyfill it, or use a widely supported

`['A', 'B', 'C'].indexOf(ctrl.type) !== -1`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an `in` operator in angular.js

However the effect can be achieved using javascript.

```
<div ng-if="['A', 'B', 'C'].indexOf(ctrl.type) > -1)">lorem ipsum</div>
```